# Building AST from Tokens (FunctionDef)?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, transpiler

I am trying to build a python transpiler to another language. I am using python's tokenizer module to get a list of Tokens and understand that the visitor pattern can be used to manipulate AST Nodes to target language.
However, I am unsure of how to convert tokens to an AST. Given how large the python grammar is it seems like there must be an easier way to build the AST rather than a bunch of "if" statements. I am specifically working on building a python FunctionDef Node for the AST. Do I have to loop through tokens and use if's to check non-terminals only?...

I have viewed tutorials such as; Super Tiny Compiler, crafting interpreters, python docs

Given a list of tokens, I want to output this ast by using recursive decent parsing (FunctionDef.body = return statement with return value).

Grammar Nodes - https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

```
tokens = [NAME:'def' NAME:'foo' LPAR:'(' NAME:'bar' COMMA:',' NAME:'verbose' RPAR:')' COLON:':' INDENT:'' NAME:'return' NAME:'bar' DEDENT:'']

ast = {
  'type': 'PROGRAM',
  'body': [
     FunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args,
                   stmt* body, expr* decorator_list, expr? returns,
                   string? type_comment)
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you're trying to achieve. Otherwise this is too vague...

Comment: Maybe take a look at Lark's codebase: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark.

Comment: Want to do the parsing myself. Tokenizing is easy so I am using the module, but I want to gain knowledge really don't want to use any pip modules but thank you anyway!

Comment: The easiest way to do this is using Python's parser, available as `ast.parse`. I honestly don't know what the learning value of not using that parser would be. One thing you might learn is the recursive descent is not nearly as simple as it is made out to be, when applied to real-world languages like Python. Personally, I think you'd be better off learning how to *write a grammar* which can be processed by one of the many available parser generators, such as Ply/Sly or Lark.

Comment: Right I wanted to learn recursive decent parsing, Super Tiny Compiler gives good start but function def's are tough because there are so many expr/stmt that can go inside a function. Do you think I could use ast.parse and implement the visit methods myself to convert each expr/stmt to my target language?

Comment: @Steve: If you're transpiling from Python, then the parse tree produced by ast.parse should give you everything you need. Despite its name, it's really more like a concrete parse tree than an abstract parse tree, so there is a lot of extraneous detail. But that's easy to walk through.

Comment: Recursive descent parsing isn't difficult at all! Check out these files (especially `rd_parser_ebnf`): https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/tree/master/2009/py_rd_parser_example. They really helped me while learning about recursive descent parsing. But the best option is as @rici said `ast.parse` should be the goto.

Comment: @xilpex: RD is trivial *if you want to write a calculator*. That's not what I called "not so simple". Take a look at `typedargslist` near the top of the Python grammar, and then tell me that "it wasn't so hard to write that grammar" :-) (And, yes, most of the complexity and repetition in that definition is forced by the LL(1) constraint.) (And that's just one example which I chose because it's close to the top.)